# Is it possible to connect Couchbase's Memcached bucket with memcached client?

Tags: php, memcached, couchbase, fuelphp

As titled and I am using PHP with Memcached.

I tried to connect to it, but it doesn't seems working.....

```
    $memcached = new \Memcached();
    $memcached->addServer('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 11211);

    $versions = $memcached->getVersion();
    foreach($versions as $version)
    {
        echo $version;
    }
```

The version returns 255.255.255.... If is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the reasons is because of the firewall and as well as Couchbase requires SASL authentication when using port 11211.

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/security/security-inside-server.html

The above code actually is working if port is being set other than 11211.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

> https://serverfault.com/questions/300172/connecting-to-memcached-what-port-to-use-php

you need a connect() command:

```
 $memcache = new Memcache; $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1',11211) or die ("Could not connect");
```

Comment: also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435949/php-memcache-connects-to-couchbase-but-cant-do-anything-else

Comment: I am using Memcached, not Memcache.  So there is no Connect() method.  And i discovered the reason is because of the firewall and as well as  Sasl authentication was introduced since 3.0, so using port 11211 required authentication.